# Is it possible to encode values without creating additional columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I understand correctly, pd.get_dummies method creates a separate column for each distinct non-numeric value in the dataframe one wants to encode, either 1 or 0. I am curious, is it possible to encode values while keeping them within the original column (i.e attribute values other than strictly 1 and 0), to avoid creating hundreds of new columns in the dataframe?

Comment: Can you provide  a minimal example?

Comment: Yes, take a look at `sklearn`s `LabelEncoder`.